# Azure WebJobs facing error using Logger via dependency injection with Unity container

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, unity-container, azure-webjobs

I am writing an Azure WebJobs which makes use of a Library, where I have to inject some classes, such as the Logger, Configuration and a Custom Storage Class.

I am trying to use Unity to implement Dependency Injection into the WebJobs function but I am facing the following error. **"No public constructor is available for type Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger"**

```
    Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage ---> Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution failed with error: No public constructor is available for type Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[ImageConsumer.Functions].

For more detailed information run Unity in debug mode: new UnityContainer().AddExtension(new Diagnostic()) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No public constructor is available for type Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[ImageConsumer.Functions]. ---> Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException: Exceçao do tipo 'Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException' foi acionada.
```

This is my main method in Program.cs

```
// To learn more about Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320976
class Program
{
    // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
    // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
    static void Main()
    {
        // Dependency injection framework to be used.
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        
        container.RegisterType<IConfiguration>();
        container.RegisterType<IStorage, Storage>();
        container.RegisterType<ILogger, Logger<Functions>>();


        var config = new JobHostConfiguration
        {
            // activate dependency injection using the container (IUnitContainer)
            JobActivator = new DependencyInjectionActivator(container)              
        };

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();

        }


        var host = new JobHost(config);
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}
```

}

This is my WebJob function

```
public class Functions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Logger instance
    /// </summary>
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    /// <summary>
    /// Configuration instance
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    /// <summary>
    /// Storage
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IStorage _storage;

    public Functions(ILogger<Functions> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IStorage storage)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _storage = storage;
    }

    // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
    // on an Azure Queue called queue.
    public async Task ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("imagestoprocessqueue")] string message, TextWriter log)
    {

        Stream blobStream = null;
        string contentType;
        string fileName = "";
        QueueImageProcessMessage queueMessage = null;
        TableProcessor tableProcessor = null;
```

... continue

What is wrong in my implementation? Would be the way I am registering (Container.RegisterType)?, Do I have to instantiate somehow theses classes in the Main method?

Any advice will be welcome, bear in mind that I am beginner, if possible instructions with examples is better, sorry but some times I got confused with short recommendations where a deeper knowledge is assumed behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register `ILogger`. `services.AddLogging` takes care of this.